# How to print the contents of the C++ keyboard/cin buffer to the console without modification?

Tags: c++

I've been working on a program that does quite a bit (at least for me) with cin and its functions, and I've been having a hard time keeping track of what's in the keyboard buffer throughout the program. It's causing me some errors - I was wondering if there was a function or a technique I could use to print the contents of the cin/keyboard buffer to the screen so that I could know what's in it at that point in the program.

I've attached the source code for anyone who's interested. It's homework for one of my classes, so apologies for anyone who sees this as too easy to even bother asking.

```
// CHAPTER 4 HOMEWORK - PROBLEM 16 - RUNNING THE RACE
/* Write a program that asks for the names of three runners and
   the time it took each of them to finish a race. The program
   should displace who came in first, second, and third place.
   Input validation: only accept positive numbers for the times*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


    // Introduction for the user
    cout << "\t\t\t    ~ RUNNING THE RACE ~\n"
         << "\t\t\t    --------------------\n\n"
         << "Welcome! In this program, you can enter the names of three runners,\n"
         << "and the times at which they finished a race. The program will organize\n"
         << "the names and times from first to last.\n\n"

         << "Are you ready to begin?\n"
         << "Press the Enter key to continue . . . ";

    cin.get();

    // declare variables and string objects
    string runnerName1, runnerName2, runnerName3;
    int minutes1, minutes2, minutes3;
    double seconds1, seconds2, seconds3;

    // RUNNER 1
    cout << "\nFirst we'll deal with runner 1.\n"
         << "Please enter runner 1's full name: ";
    getline(cin, runnerName1);
    cout << "Okay! Now for " << runnerName1 << "'s time.\n"
         << "First, enter " << runnerName1 << "'s minutes (a whole number): ";
    cin >> minutes1;
    cout << "And now enter " << runnerName1 << "'s seconds: ";
    cin >> seconds1;


    // RUNNER 2
    cout << "\nNext we'll deal with runner 2.\n"
         << "Please enter runner 2's full name: ";
    cin.ignore(); // because of the remaining space in the keyboard buffer leftover from the last cin >> statement
    getline(cin, runnerName2);
    cout << "Good! Now for " << runnerName2 << "'s time.\n"
         << "Enter " << runnerName2 << "'s minutes (a whole number): ";
    cin >> minutes2;
    cout << "Now enter " << runnerName2 << "'s seconds: ";
    cin >> seconds2;


    // RUNNER 3
    cout << "\nFinally, runner 3.\n"
         << "Please enter runner 3's full name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, runnerName3);
    cout << "What is " << runnerName3 << "'s time?\n"
         << "First, enter " << runnerName3 << "'s minutes (a whole number): ";
    cin >> minutes3;
    cout << "Now enter " << runnerName3 << "'s seconds: ";
    cin >> seconds3;

    // display the gathered data in a useful manner
    cout << "___________________________________________\n" // border

         << "RESULTS:\n\n"

         << "NAME:\t\t\tTIME:\n";

    // make sure any extra seconds entered above 60 gets added to the number of minutes
    while (seconds1 >= 60.0)
    {
        seconds1 -= 60.0;
        minutes1 += 1;
    }

    while (seconds2 >= 60.0)
    {
        seconds2 -= 60.0;
        minutes2 += 1;
    }

    while (seconds3 >= 60.0)
    {
        seconds3 -= 60.0;
        minutes3 += 1;
    }

    // now for the results . . . 
    cout << runnerName1 << "\t" << minutes1 << ":" << seconds1 << endl;
    cout << runnerName2 << "\t" << minutes2 << ":" << seconds2 << endl;
    cout << runnerName3 << "\t" << minutes3 << ":" << seconds3 << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, this was built on VS 2012 Express, for anyone who has multiple versions. I didn't use any windows-exclusive code within the program though (eg system("pause")), so it should work fine with other compilers.

Comment: Post your code here, not as a a link.

Comment: You should be able to examine the inner details of `cin` using the debugger. Do you really need a portable API?

Comment: As a general advice, you probably want to use a loop for this piece of code instead of copying the same block of code 3 times.

Comment: @Barmar could this be accomplished with the DataTips feature in VS? Do you know of an analogous feature in an alternative IDE? And as for the portability, I guess I didn't think about it that way - either would do really. It would still be a cool trick to make it work within the code itself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about VS. I don't know why you would need to do this within the code, since it seems like you just want to do this to troubleshoot problems you're having processing the input. That's what debuggers are for.

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/ for the public interface to the `streambuf` class, which underlies all the buffered input and output classes.

Comment: why don't you use `peek`

Comment: @jnbbender `peek` is good for one and only one character. OP cannot see the whole buffer contents. rdbuf is headed in the right direction, but cin isn't very friendly when it comes to sharing what's going on in it's internals. OP might be better off calling `getline` on cin, writing the line into a much friendlier `stringstream`, and consuming the `stringstream`.

Comment: @user4581301 unfortunately I'd consider that "modification" - an observer effect.

Comment: @jnbbender It is, or I would have posted an answer. Queue the Stones, cuz I don't think the OP's getting any satisfaction.